# How to get the max date per month

Tags: max, abap, opensql

I have a table like

```
kunnr        date            posnr
30001        28/5/2017       1
30001        25/5/2017       2
30001        15/5/2017       3
30001        25/4/2017       4
30001        20/4/2017       5
30002        15/5/2017       6
30002        25/4/2017       7
```

I want for every new kunnr to get the record with the max date per month, namely the max for May and max for April etc.

OK, I will sort the table loop at it and for every new kunnr .... how I will get the record for max date for each month?

Thanks in advance
Elias

PS: sth went wrong and I realise that I do not get what I want. I have the following lines in a table

```
0000527746  1000    10.06.2017  20170718100757.5010080
0000527746  1000    10.06.2017  20170718100757.5039300
0000527746  1000    11.06.2017  20170718100839.9209480
0000527746  1000    11.06.2017  20170718100906.3337170
0000527746  1000    24.07.2017  20170718095843.3555610
0000527746  1000    24.07.2017  20170718100209.2203570
0000527746  1000    24.07.2017  20170718100757.4970390
```

and I want to select the last date of each month namely I want the select to bring me the following lines

```
0000527746  1000    11.06.2017  20170718100906.3337170
0000527746  1000    24.07.2017  20170718100757.4970390
```

I use the following sql

```
select bukrs kunnr dat max( time ) as time
    from zcollectoraction into corresponding fields of table it_collectoraction
    where bukrs = p_bukrs and
          kunnr in so_kunnr and
          dat   in so_date
    group by bukrs kunnr dat.
```

but it displays the following lines

```
0000527746  1000    11.06.2017  20170718100906.3337170
0000527746  1000    11.06.2017  20170718100906.3337170
0000527746  1000    24.07.2017  20170718100757.4970390
```

What to do in order to have 1 line per month?

Thanks
Elias

Comment: Do you mean the last day of any month? New kunnr's will not be in your table yet...

Comment: Can you add the expected result for the example?

Answer (score 4):

Why not to use aggregate functions just during select from DB? It is more efficient that looping internal table.

```
SELECT k~bukrs_vf, k~kunnr, k~erdat, MAX( p~posnr ) AS T
  FROM vbak AS k
  JOIN vbap AS p
    ON k~vbeln = p~vbeln
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_result)
 GROUP BY bukrs_vf, kunnr, k~erdat
 ORDER BY bukrs_vf.
```

Note, that the above query will select only those kunnrs which have corresponding positions in `vbap`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Suncatcher. Just 2 things. Firstly, I want the MAX by bukrs, kunnr, date and if there are are more than 1 rows then we will take the 1 with MAX posnr. I understand that then I will loop to the internal table and took the remaining fields.   Thanks a lot ELIAS